# Jenkins Pipeline based on groovy : unable to push to the git: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, groovyshell, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to push some changes to the git repository using groovy pipeline syntax. But I am unable to push. Can anyone help me here.

Pipeline Syntax:

```
        sh '''
        #git checkout pkg_version
        touch README
        git add .
        git status
        git commit -m "Updated Package Version"
        git remote -v
        sshagent(credentialsId) {
            git push origin pkg_version
        }
        #git push origin pkg_version
        '''
```

Jenkins Error:

```
origin  ssh://jenkins@gerrit:29418/sfdx_nar (fetch)
origin  ssh://jenkins@gerrit:29418/sfdx_nar (push)
+ git push origin pkg_version
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
[Pipeline] }
```

Comment: Did you try push anything using Jenkins user from the same machine ? Meaning  SSH to the Jenkins slave machine and do the push using the Jenkins user ?

Comment: Yes I pushed with Jenkins User(Service Account)

Comment: Does you sh script work when running on that machine without adopting it? To me it looks like you‘re trying to call a pipeline step ‘sshagent’ from within a shell script.

Comment: Yes it was working with plain git commands. Yes, I am trying to call within a script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using SSHAgent like this in your pipeline:

```
steps{
  sshagent(['your-credential-id']) {
    sh "git-steps..."
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I got an error with the above syntax:


[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'steps' found among steps dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients,  viewsTabBar, weather, zfs, zip] or globals [currentBuild, docker, env, fileLoader, params, scm]
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:149)